# How to create volatile table inn teradata using SAS dataset without sql sandbox

Tags: sas, teradata

I have a SAS dataset and I need to create a volatile table in Teradata using the SAS dataset. But, I do not have a sandbox to store the table on Teradata server. Is there a way that I can create a Teradata volatile table from a SAS dataset without SQL Sandbox.

Comment: What is SQL sandbox? What does it have to do with SAS or Teradata?

Comment: Sandbox meant that you have a storage space on teradata server to create permanent tables or views..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty simple to create a volatile table in Teradata, just use the `dbmstemp=yes` option on your libname statement.

```
libname TDWORK teradata connection=global dbmstemp=yes .... ;
data tdwork.test1 ;
  set sashelp.class ;
run;
```

Make sure to use the `connection=global` option on all of your LIBNAME and CONNECT statements so that all of the connections to Teradata use the same session so you can see your volatile table.  Keep at least one of the libref's open so that the connection persists.

Then you could also use passthru SQL to create a volatile table.

```
proc sql ;
  connect to teradata (connection=global .... );
  execute (
    create volatile table test2 as (
      select * from test1
    ) with data on commit preserve rows 
  ) by teradata;
quit;
```

Or to reference the volatile tables in pass thru SQL code.

So if you wanted to pull out of Teradata all the records from `MYDB.MYTABLE` where `NAME` was in the list of names you uploaded into the volatile table `TEST1` you made with the first data step above you could use code like this:

```
proc sql ;
  connect to teradata (connection=global .... );
  create table mytest as select * from connection to teradata 
  ( select * from mydb.mytable 
    where name in (select name from test1)
  );
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, this helps.. To add another query to the result of this, If I have database x and I want to join a volatile table with a permanent table in db x, is it possible to do that. I use the below code:

proc sql;
connect to teradata (server=,...,connection = global);
create table lib.table as select * from connection to teradata (
select variable1, variable2 from test2 join x.tab);

lib is the sas libname because I am trying to create a SAS dataset based on joining a volatile and a permanent table in Teradata, x is the database in Teradata and test2 is the volatile table.

Comment: No need to pull it back to SAS by using an output SAS libref that is pointing to the same Teradata server. Just use the `execute (....) by teradata;` statement to run pure Teradata code.  However if your output libref was pointing to SAS datasets (or some other external database) then you would want to use the syntax in your comment.

Comment: Do not reference SAS things like the libref `lib` in the pass thru SQL. You can only reference Teradata things.  Volatile tables do not normally need database prefix on them, but I think if they do then they are in your personal  database (even if you have 0 space to store permanent objects). `create table libref.sasdsn as select * from connection to teradata (select a.x,b.y from volatile_table a inner join dbname.tblname b on a.id =b.id) ;`

Comment: libname lib teradata
    server=...
    authdomain="..."
    connection=global
    proc sql;
    connect to teradata
    (server=... authdomain="..." connection=global);
    create table saslib.table as select * from connection to teradata (
    select variable1, variable 2 from lib.volatile_table join db.x);


x is a permanent table in database DB, saslib is the sas libname, I get an error saying the volatile table lib.volatile_table does not exists

Comment: You normally do not use two level names for volatile tables. So if you made a volatile table named `fred` then you would reference it as just `fred` in the Teradata code.

Comment: libname z "sas path";
    libname x teradata server=. authdomain=. connection=global    
    proc sql;
    connect to teradata(server=.authdomain=.
    connection=global);
    execute (create volatile table id(id INT) on commit 
    preserve rows) by teradata;
    execute (commit work) by teradata;
    quit;  
    proc sql;
    insert into x.id select id from z.sas_table;
    proc sql;
    connect to teradata(server=.authdomain=.
    connection=global);
    create table z.sas_table1 as select * from connection to
    teradata (select variable1, variable2 from x.id join db.y)

Comment: I cannot access the CHAT page.